# universal and uniform initialization: `double` to `int`

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, list-initialization

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. C++11\C++14.

For `int`:

```
constexpr int ci1 {50};
constexpr int ci2 {500};

char c1 {ci1}; // OK
char c2 {ci2}; // compilation error
```

I.e. the *universal and uniform initialization* can check the value in the compilation mode (from `int` to `char`). This case was mentioned by *Bjarne Stroustrup* in his book.

I expected that this is true for case *`double` to `int`*,but it doesn't work for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3:

```
constexpr double cd {4.0};
int i1 {cd}; // compilation error
```

Error message:

> C2397 conversion from 'double' to 'int' requires a narrowing
>   conversion

Is it correct behaviour (for my second code example) or maybe it is specific for Visual Studio?

Comment: Please include the compilation error in your post.

Comment: Floating-to-integer is unconditionally narrowing, regardless of the source value. See [\[dcl.init.list\]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7).

Comment: I added the error message.

Comment: @T.C. But why? For similar examples conversion happens without distortion of original value. What does this situation differ from my first variant of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion from double to int is narrowing, because doubles represent rational numbers. (0.5) Since it is not necessary exact (1. could be 1.000000001), conversion would loose information.

Use explicit casts for such conversions, and everything will be fine, or dont use universal initialization.

Answer (score 1):

`double` to `int` conversion is always considered narrowing, which is why Bjarne Stroustrup creates a `narrow_cast<>` implementation in his book for such casting.

Comment: But why? For similar examples conversion happens without distortion of original value. What does this situation differ from my first variant of  code?

Comment: @Andrey I believe that in some implementation, in theory, it might include distortion as AFAIK standard does not require whole values to be precisely represented by double